# Twilio iOS iPhone MMS video thumbnail inconsistencies

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio, mms, cloudinary

Can't figure out why some videos have a thumbnail and others show an icon. I've tried sending to different iOS devices on different networks. I've tried sending all sorts of different videos with different settings. I've looked over all the metadata I can. I've been serving some of the videos from Cloudinary and playing with settings there as well. Android on the other hand doesn't seem to suffer any of these issues.

[image: Twilio iOS iPhone MMS video thumbnail inconsistencies]

Comment: Hey Adam, Twilio evangelist here.  I'd suggest dropping a line to our awesome support team.  If you provide them with some Message Sids they can work closely to see what exactly is going on with both Twilio and once we hand the message off to the carrier for delivery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the videos from varying sources, is it possible that they are of different [media types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types) and thus display differently in iOS?

Though this does sound like something that would be best addressed on a per message basis where the support team can check the finer details if you give them the [message SID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-uri).